# regex does not work in swift

Tags: swift, regex, line-breaks, negative-lookbehind

I am using a regular expression to find all `\n` occurrences in a string.

The regular expression itself is working:

[image]

The expression finds `\n` but not `\\n`. Which is, what I want.

However, when I want to implement this in Swift for an iOS-application I get the error: `invalid regex: The value „(?<!\)\n“ is invalid`.

My code looks like this (after implementing the `\` approach from the comments:

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, \n \\n playground"

let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<!\\\\)\\n", options: .caseInsensitive)

let matches = regex?.matches(in: str, options: .anchored, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count))

print(matches)
```

`matches` is nil. It should find `\n`.

Comment: Because you need two backslashes in a string literal to define a regex escape, so you need 4 backslashes in a pattern to match a ``\``

Comment: This does not work. It will not find the regex matches.

Comment: It does work. You just do not understand your input. At regexr, your `Hello \n World` contains ``\`` and `n` combination that can be written as `"Hello \\n World"` in the Swift string literal, and accordingly, `Hello \\n World` string in the regexr tester should be written as `"Hello \\\\n World"`. That all means that your strings in the online tester are not the same strings you used in your Swift test.

Comment: `"Hello \\n \\\\n world"` will not be found by the expression `"(?<!\\\\)\\n"` in Swift.

Comment: Right, because your `Hello \n \\n world` string does not match your `(?<!\\)\n` regex that matches any LF symbol (a newline char) that has no ``\`` char immediately to the left of it.

Comment: Ok. Well the goal is to only find `\n`and not `\\n`, `\\\n`...

Comment: To find a combination of two chars, ``\`` and `n`, not preceded with ``\``, use `(?<!\\)\\n` that is defined with `"(?<!\\\\)\\\\n"` string literal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172979/discussion-between-walterbeiter-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: still no matches found

Comment: 1) Remove `.anchored` as it makes the regex engine to only search at the start of the string, 2) your `"(?<!\\\\)\\n"` matches 1 LF in `"Hello, \n \\n playground"` ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/cyteGY/1)) - when the search is unanchored.

Comment: works. thanks removed the .anchored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is compiled with the [`.anchored`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression.matchingoptions/1410858-anchored) option that requires the pattern to only match at the start of the string:

> Specifies that matches are limited to those at the start of the search range.

You need to remove this option, e.g.

```
let matches = regex?.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.count))
```

Note the `"(?<!\\\\)\\n"` string literal defines a `(?<!\\)\n` regex pattern that matches

- `(?<!\\)` - a location in string that is not immediately preceded with a `\` char
- `\n` - a newline character, LF.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/cyteGY/1).